# Proof of the fact that every continuous function is Borel measurable.

Tags: measure-theory, borel-sets, borel-measures

I am doing a course on Measure theory in my Masters' course.I try to do proofs on my own whenever possible.

**Definition**

A function $f:X\subset \mathbb {R\to R}$ is called Borel measurable if the inverse image of every Borel set is a Borel, set.

Now,I saw a theorem which I tried to prove on my own:

**Th.** Every continuous function is Borel measurable.

My proof goes as follows:

It suffices to show that $f^{-1}(a,\infty)$ is a Borel set for each $a\in \mathbb R$.

Now,$f$ is continuous,so $f^{-1}(a,\infty)$ is open in $X$.

So,$f^{-1}(a,\infty)=U\cap X$ for some $U$ open in $X$.

$U$ being open in $\mathbb R$ is a Borel set in $\mathbb R$.

So,$U\cap X$ is a Borel set in $X$.

Thus,$f$ is Borel measurable.

Is the proof ok?The only confusion I have is the meaning of Borel set in $X$ for a subset $X$ of $\mathbb R$,does that mean intersection of $X$ with a Borel set in $\mathbb R$ as I have used here?

Comment: I guess this is fine. Also there are many exact questions in the site  .

Comment: @IvinBabu What about the definition of Borel set in $X\subset \mathbb R$.

Comment: Yes. Borel sets, in any topological space,  are those sets formed  from open sets through the operation of countable union, countable intersections, and complement. Since open sets in X are intersections of open sets in $\Bbb R$ with X, your definition of borel set should be fine.